# Contract testing with pact, golang and xml response

Tags: xml, go, pact

How to write dsl matchers against xml response in golang using pact-go. The official documentation [https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/go] does not say anything about it. It has examples for pact js but not for pact-go

Refered to the official documentation, but found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Pact Go does not yet support XML. You could raise a feature request and/or put together a PR to support it.

If you'd like to do that, please join the #pact-go channel in our community [Slack workspace](https://slack.pact.io) and you can discuss it with the maintainer group.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew for clearing it up.  Is it possible with pact js. The documentation says , we have to use xmlBuilder and convert it to json. So ultimately , its like we are doing transformation of response to json before verifying in consumer as well as provider. Or is there more direct way available?